# Interpretation of product measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume $X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1\\ X_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is a random vector. What does it mean when we say the probability measure on X is a product measure on $(X_1, X_2)$? If I am right, by definition it means if $A = \begin{bmatrix} A_1\\ A_2 \end{bmatrix}$, then

$P(X \in A) =  P(X_1 \in A_1, X_2 \in A_2) = P_1(X_1 \in A_1) P_2(X_2 \in A_2).$

Does it mean that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes -- provided you replace "the probability measure on $X$" by "the distribution of $X$", "a product measure on $(X_1, X_2)$" by "a product measure", and $P_1$ and $P_2$ by $P$.